# Get explorer.exe to load my extension from startup

Tags: c++, dll, hook, windows-shell, shell-extensions

**Context to prevent an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):** (Because there very well might be a simplier solution)

My goal is to track `explorer.exe`'s file movement when the user drags files around (as well as uses clipboard cut and copy stuff).  I tried to solve this with a Windows Shell Extension, however the interfaces that I implemented never seemed to do trigger.  I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) guide from CodeProject which worked beautifully.  However, when I implemented the [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, none of my functions were ever called by `explorer.exe` during these user operations (is there another place I'm supposed to add to the `*.rgs` file from the tutorial?  Some specific registration location for the IFileOperation interface like txtfile was for the context menu?).

In response, have written a DLL file that hooks `ntdll.dll` function calls using `mhook` and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks) other CodeProject tutorial, which all takes place within `DLLMain`.  Instead of using the `AppInit` registry entry as in the tutorial, I used a [third party DLL injection program](http://securityxploded.com/remote-dll-injector.php) to force `explorer.exe` to load my DLL.  By filtering `NtReadFile`, `NtWriteFile`, and `NtSetInformationFile` calls, I can differentiate between move and copy operations.  It worked pretty well!

**Problem:**

Code injection is hacky though, so I went back and merged my `DLLMain` with the first guide so that my hooking code resides within a shell extension.  When `explorer.exe` loads the shell extension, my hooking code gets executed as well.  Well, `explorer.exe` is smart and only loads DLLs as it needs them.  In order for my hooking code to start working, I need to right click a text file in order to invoke the original guide's shell extension code, at which point the DLL seems to stay loaded from then on.

**Question:**

Is there a shell extension interface that I can pseudo implement in order to get `explorer.exe` to load my shell extension on startup, and never unload it?  Is there a more elegant solution to what I'm doing?

Edit: There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718670/what-is-a-reliable-way-to-get-a-dll-to-load-when-windows-explorer-loads?rq=1) concerning a BHO, which loads with both `explorer.exe` and `iexplorer.exe` at start up.  I had thought it was just an IE thing when I read that, but I was wrong.  There is an additional key (NoExplorer) you can write to prevent `explorer.exe` from loading it, but is there a similar command to prevent IE from loading it?  All of my searches keep bringing up NoExplorer.

Edit: Through a little bit of empirical experimentation, the [ICopyHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776049(v=vs.85).aspx) interface is as close to a persistent shell extension as it gets.  The reason IFileOperation wasn't being called was because `explorer.exe` does not call it, but rather it comes from other programs requesting the shell to do a specific operation under that interface.  In any case, I've implemented a rather empty ICopyHook shell extension and it seems to load into `explorer.exe` shortly after startup, although it is very nondeterministic.  If anyone has a better solution, please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is an additional key (NoExplorer) you can write to prevent explorer.exe from loading it, but is there a similar command to prevent IE from loading it?
```

Simply return **FALSE** in DllMain **DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH** when your shell extension is loaded by Internet Explorer.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but for some reason my DLL wasn't even being loaded from the HBO folder.  Either I have the DLL formatted wrong somehow (some interface I'm supposed to implement maybe?) or I entered it in the registry incorrectly.

Comment: Hmmmm, you are victim of your code. Returns TRUE in DllMain also for Regsvr32.exe.